# I dont want my ubuntu server to be accessed from outside my house

Tags: server, ssh

I am studying cyber security so I wanted to try wazuh, to get familiar with it. I turned an old desktop into an Ubuntu server, and got wazuh installed on it. I do not want the server exposed to the internet, because my knowledge of servers, Linux, and networking is limited. And I don't want to jeopardize my home network because I did something wrong or did not secure something properly. I though I had it right but when I turned my vpn on and tried to ssh into my server it worked. MY router from my ISP provider doesn't let me change any settings. So basically I am asking if there is a way to make sure my server can only be signed onto from my home network.

Comment: The fool-proof way is the keep it separate from the internet, no ethernet cable, no wifi, until you know better how to keep things fairly safe. You can connect other computers to the server with a small separate local network without connection to the internet, or when testing, you can disconnect the router from internet. - You can also discuss this with experienced people at the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org).

Comment: Thanks for the help that is what I will do just disconnect the ethernet cord when  I am not using it. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you have a hardware firewall at home, and don't forward any ports to your server, you have for all practical purposes isolated it from the internet.